# Why does 'SCM Status' break when file system is irregular?

Tags: git, textmate, textmate2

Rather than a simple directory on my disk, I work on a project that's inside a Disk Image (Case-Sensitive, Journaled). TM2 works great, but I couldn't get the GitBundle extensions to function, including the `Go => SCM Status` menu item.

First, I thought my `TM_GIT` property wasn't set, but later added an entry in my `~/.tm_properties` file.

Reading odd entries from the [Mailing List](http://old.nabble.com/TM2%3a-SCM-button-and-Go--%3E-SCM-Status-td33002246.html#a33002246), regarding `SMB disks`, I moved an instance of my project onto my Local Disk, and suddenly the Git menus (most of them) worked perfectly.

Restating question: Why does the Git Bundle fail here, but not in TM1.5.1 ?

(I think my mailbox would explode if I joined the TM mailing list, and I refuse to sign up with 'Old Nabble' which clearly states "we're going to save your password because it's okay")

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand your problem. Check two things, 
*Maybe its because TM2 relies on absolute paths, with TM_BUNDLE_SUPPORT type path variable. There is one for project root which can be set in .tm_properties (try that)
*Also its seems like TM2 resolving symlinks is not the same as regular directories.If your are mounting your directory then maybe that causes issues.